# get src value from multiple images and split to single variables

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get src value of some images but i will get it only from first one image.. is here way to get value from all images?

```
<div class="cube-box--cube active">
    <img class="cube-box--cube__img" src="
    {$basePath}/assets/img/animation/scenery2.jpg" alt="scenery2">

    <div class="white-cover"></div>
    <p class="cube-box--cube__text">
      <span class="fix-size">Electrostatics</span>
    Neutral
    </p>
</div>

<div class="cube-box--cube active">
    <img class="cube-box--cube__img" src="
    {$basePath}/assets/img/animation/scenery3.jpg" alt="scenery3">

    <div class="white-cover"></div>
    <p class="cube-box--cube__text">
      <span class="fix-size">Electrostatics</span>
    Neutral
    </p>
</div>

var imgSrc = $('.cube-box--cube').filter('.active').find("img").attr("src");
console.log(imgSrc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do it

```
var srcs = [ ];

$.each($('.cube-box--cube').filter('.active').find("img"), function() {
    srcs.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

If you want to use map, you may need to:

```
...find("img").get().map(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map all the matches to an array like this

`var imgSources = $('.cube-box--cube')
  .filter('.active')
  .find("img")
  .map(function (index, image) {
    return image.src;
  });`